# How can you check if one name refers to the same symbol as another?

Tags: c++, clang

I'd like to check if a fully-qualified name and an unqualified or partly-qualified name refer to the same symbol, even if one name isn't defined.  That is, I'd like to be able to write something like this as part of a refactoring tool:

```
namespace A {
void f() {};
}

namespace B {
namespace A {};

  bool g() {
    // returns false
    return is_same_symbol<A::f, ::A::f>::value;
  }
}

namespace C {
  bool h() {
    // returns true
    return is_same_symbol<A::f, ::A::f>::value;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I'd like to check to be able to check if two different symbols refer to the same thing, even if one doesn't exist." That does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yeah, I know, I'm not sure how to verbalize it.  I suppose a better way of saying it is "I'd like to check if a fully-qualified name and an unqualified or partly qualified name refer to the same symbol"

Comment: If a symbol is not defined, and you try to use it, you'll get a compiler error, plain and simple.

Comment: You could silence that error and instead use a different function with SFINAE

Comment: @qxz I'm trying to figure out teh correct SFINAE incantation for this to check if a free function of a given name exists.  I'm not much of a metaprogramming ninja, unfortunately.  If I can answer "Does A::f exist?", then I can either return false if A::f doesn't exist, or return &A::f == &::A::f if it does

Comment: @JonCohen I'm a bit curious as to why you want to do this. What is your ultimate goal / bigger program you're trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

You clarify in a comment:

> I'm trying to figure out the correct SFINAE incantation for this to check if a free function of a given name exists.

You can't.

When you say *a free function called* `foo` *exists*, what do you mean?

It has to be one of:

*The compiler has seen a declaration of* `foo`:

```
... int foo(int i);
```

or:

*The compiler has seen a definition of* `foo`:

```
... int foo(int i) {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

A definition is also a declaration, so if the compiler has not
seen a declaration of `foo` then it hasn't seen a definition either.

Suppose you're trying to SFINAE-probe whether `foo` is declared.
If the compiler has not even seen a declaration of `foo` then *any*
subsequent code you write that uses `foo` as a name will provoke
a compile error in the vein:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'foo'
```

You can't write code to SFINAE-probe whether `foo` is declared because
you can't write C++ that uses undeclared names, period.

Suppose you're trying to SFINAE-probe whether `foo` is *defined*.
To do that, you'd first have to have *declaration* of foo - either
one you've written yourself or one that you've got from some header file.

But of course, given a declaration of `foo`, the compiler *can't tell whether
or not it is defined* and doesn't care, except in the special cases that the function 
is declared as `static` or `inline` or in an anonymous namespace. 
Otherwise, it leaves the finding or not finding of a definition to the linker.

Generally then, SFINAE-probing the existence of function *definitions* is likewise
a non-starter. And even if `foo` is declared `static`
or `inline` or in an anonymous namespace, and lacks a definition within the compilation unit, any
code that uses `foo` *in conformity with its declaration* remains well-formed
code; so even in those cases SFINAE-probing for is-it-defined remains meaningless.